# Converting String to Char array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string, serversocket

I am using the toCharArray method to convert a string to an array of type char but every time i try to print the array, it is printing numbers instead of the characters stored in the string. When i print the string the characters are printed just fine.

```
char[] nArray = capitalizedSentence.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < nArray.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(nArray[i] + '\n');
        }
```

EXAMPLE:
If my capitalizedSentence string has the value "Saad", when i convert it to a character array and print it, it prints the following:

```
93
75
75
78
```

can someone please help me so that it prints the individual characters stored in the capitalizedSentence string?

Comment: Character class toString() implementation probably prints the numeric value. You have a char array.

Comment: I want it to print the individual characters in the string separately.

Comment: you need to let it in the string. `System.out.println(capitalizedSentence .substring(i, i+1) + '\n');`

Comment: The printing is just to make sure that the characters have been properly stored inside the array nArray.

Comment: Even now it is still printing the same numeric values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nArray[i]` is a `char`; so is the `'\n'` constant. Character is an unsigned integral type, so characters are added together in the same way as all integers - numerically. When an addition happens, you end up with an `int`, not a `char`, so calling `println` on it produces a numeric result.

Removing `+ '\n'` will fix the problem. You would get a newline character from `println`, so all characters would appear on a new line.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/UuSBXD)

Comment: your explanation is so much better.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `'\n'` with `"\n"`

Why? Because the compiler sees you adding 2 characters together, to the compiler `char` and `int` primitive data types are considered to interchangeable and so the `+` is actually adding the 2 int values together. Using double quotes will tell the compiler that you are adding a string to a character.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you. Use for-each loop

```
char[] nArray = capitalizedSentence.toCharArray();
for(Character c: nArray ){
    System.out.println(c);
}
```